# When does Armor of Agathys take effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, damage-reduction

When does Armor of Agathys take effect given that Damage Reduction happens first?

Consider a character with Heavy Armor Master which says:

> - While you are wearing heavy armor, bludgeoning,
>     piercing, and slashing damage that you take from non
>     magical weapons is reduced by 3.

and *Armor of Agathys* which says:

> You gain 5 temporary hit points for the duration. If a creature hits you with a melee attack while you have these hit
>   points, the creature takes 5 cold damage.

If the character is struck for 3 or fewer points—all damage would be negated by Heavy Armor Master—does the attacker still take the 5 points of damage from the Armor of Agathys? or because the Armor of Agathys did not absorb any damage is the attacker unaffected?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would say the Armor of Agathys would still take effect - it's description says if a creature **hits** you with a melee weapon, not **damages** you. There are a variety of effects that could mitigate the damage that wouldn't prevent it from being a hit in the first place.

This also makes in-game-world sense; the spell is putting off cold that hurts people from you and your gear; the heavy armor master ability is letting you shrug off attacks that hit your armor, so there's no good simulationist reason the cold shouldn't affect the attacker either.

Comment: Go see http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53504/can-someone-explain-how-hps-stack-with-various-spells for ordering of DR, temp hp, etc.

Comment: Yep. And it's possible to deal zero damage on a hit, as confirmed by Crawford [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/08/15/deal-zero-damage/) and [here](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/06/25/minimum-damage/), so even if the damage is reduced to 0, the attacker is still affected by Armor of Agathys.