# Fire Shield and Shield interaction

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, reactions, triggered-actions

An awakened cat with wizard levels has *[fire shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fire-shield)* active, and is melee attacked by a goblin within 5 feet of it. The goblin hits the cat but exceeds the cats AC by 4 or less.

*Fire shield* states:

> In addition, **whenever a creature within 5 feet of you hits you with a melee attack,** the shield erupts in flame. The attacker takes 2d8 ... damage..

Hooray! That pesky goblin will get their comeuppance. However, the cat does not feel like taking any damage from this attack, so it casts *[shield](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield)* which has the following cast time and trigger:

> 1 reaction, which you take **when you are hit by an attack** or targeted by the *magic missile* spell

So the cat has clearly been hit by the attack, triggering *fire shield* and allowing it to take a reaction to cast *shield* as well. But *shield* has this effect:

> ... Until the start of your next turn, **you have a +5 bonus to AC, including against the triggering attack,** ...

Which would cause the attack to miss! Now we have Schroedinger's *fire shielded* cat!

Does the damage from *fire shield* affect the attacking creature when you also cast *shield* to negate the attack? Or does negating the hit also negate the trigger which allowed *shield* to be cast at all?

Comment: Very similar question: "[Does blocking an attack with the Shield spell still trigger Armor of Agathys?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/122516)"

Comment: @Medix2 That is a good question that I missed in my search, thank you! It does appear to still be somewhat contested, based on an answer outperforming the accepted answer, and neither answer feels definitive.

Comment: It may be different enough for shield/fire shield vs shield/armor of agathys, but i'm having a hard time parsing what it may be. It really feels like a duplicate and that you're not totally satisfied with the answer. But if that's the case, you should bounty that question.

Comment: @NautArch That's fair. I'm fine closing this as a duplicate, as it is very similar, although new information may be around since that questions asking. I'll do some digging, and if necessary ask for a reopen with new information.

Comment: The mechanic in question is identical, so I agree that linked question is functionally a dupe. However, I don't think better answers are possible than those already given to that earlier question; unfortunately, it is possible to coherently interpret the rules to support either interpretation (though designer commentary clearly indicates which interpretation is intended.)

Comment: Related: [Do reactions interrit triggers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/do-reactions-interrupt-their-triggers-or-not)?

Comment: @Randomorph If you also feel something isn't clearly answered, just say what that is on the duplicate question and put up a bounty. It's a great way to get further clarity.

Comment: @Carcer I disagree that it is clear based on developer comments, as the cited comments are about additional triggers on the attack itself, rather than multiple triggers reacting to the same event which may or may not cancel each other. I do agree that the questions are fundamentally the same however.

Comment: @Randomorph eh, IMO it extrapolates transitively to any effect which depends on the attack hitting whether that effect is part of the attack or from some other source, but I take your point.

Comment: @Carcer yeah, I would agree were it not for the fact that this interpretation would also make Shield no longer having a trigger to react to. This is the type of thing that is definitely _not_ transitive, as order of operations matters.

Comment: As a side note...not sure a cat can perform a somatic component with their paws. But that's really more likely up to a DM.

Comment: @NautArch oh I agree, the cat was more for comedic effect!